# How can i an add image overlay depending on the options in the polygon properties in a leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I have a multi-polygon geojson file ( mapInfo ) that has one of the properties named "field_hazards". The hazards include "gale/storm, heavy rain, thunderstorm and Freezing rain "
How can i an add image overlay depending on the field_hazard options?
Note the geojson file is got dynamically as a drupal feed.
I have made the following code but it returns an empty map, the polygons are not rendered.

```js
function getImage(d) {
  return d === 'Freezing Rain' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/43n.png" :
    d === 'Thunderstorm' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/11.png" :
    d === 'Heavy Rain' ? "http://my:8082/weather-images/02n.png" :
    d === 'Gale\/Storm' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/15.png" :
    "http://my:8082/images/weather-images/09.png";
}
var imageUrl = getImage(feature.properties.field_hazards);
var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map).bringToBack();
var boxOptions = {
  fillOpacity: 0,
  opacity: 0,
  onEachFeature: onEachBox
};
//create the image interaction box
var imageBox = L.geoJson(mapInfo, boxOptions).addTo(map);
//zoom in to fit GeoJSON layer
map.fitBounds(imageBox.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to create separate image overlays for each feature, you will want to create them within your `onEachBox` function:

```js
function onEachBox(feature, layer) {
  var imageBounds = layer.getBounds();
  var imageUrl = getImage(feature.properties.field_hazards);
  var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map).bringToBack();
}
```

Here is an example showing this at work:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/4vtrr5wn/